# Using different value for same key in yii2 i18n

Tags: yii2

i', trying to incorporate multi-language functionality into my project and i have a situation whereby the same key has multiple meaning and i wounder how to fix this for example i have in my project

```
return[
    'Home' => '首页', //meaning ‘Home page’
 ]`
```

Now the case is i also have some over words with Home as the key but have another meaning like thus

```
'Home' => '主队', //meaning ‘Home team’
```

how  can  actualize this using the same key "Home" but giving them different meaning on different part of my project

Comment: Are you talking about translating strings with `Yii::t()` method?

Comment: @ Michal Hynčica yes am talking about translating with Yii::t() method, and i have a key that has two meanings in chinese language how do i use the same key and also achieve the translation with different meaning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options how to deal with situation like that.

### Using categories

The proper way would be using different categories for different meanings. To do that you have to configure the translations for two (or more) different categories, for example like that.

```php
'components' => [
    // ...
    'i18n' => [
        'translations' => [
            'app*' => [
                'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                'fileMap' => [
                    'app' => 'app.php',
                    'app/match' => 'match.php',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

Your app.php translation file will look like this

```php
return [
    'Home' => '首页', //meaning ‘Home page’
];
```

And your match.php translation file will look like this:

```php
return [
    'Home' => '主队', //meaning ‘Home team’
];
```

Then you will call translations like this where the meaning is home page:

```php
Yii::t('app', 'Home');
```

And like this where the meaning is home team:

```php
Yii::t('app/match', 'Home');
```

If you are using `yii message` command to generate translation files you might need to set the `fileMap` in it's config to make sure all files are generated properly.

### Forcing translations for source language

This way is more like hack than proper solution. You can force the i18n component to translate text even if the source and app language are same. You can use that to have two different keys that are same in the english translations but different in other.

The configuration would look like:

```
'components' => [
    // ...
    'i18n' => [
        'translations' => [
            'app*' => [
                'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                'forceTranslation' => true,
                'fileMap' => [
                    'app' => 'app.php',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

The english app.php translation file:

```php
return [
    'Home page' => 'Home',
    'Home team' => 'Home',
];
```

The chinese app.php translation file:

```php
return [
    'Home page' => '首页',
    'Home team' => '主队', 
];
```

You will use `Yii::t('app', 'Home page')` or `Yii::t('app', 'Home team')` in your code.

Comment: thanks for your help, i will go with the first approch as i think it best solve my problem, but i tried it and i got this error message, i think i'm missing something, i placed the match.php file in the same directory as app.php the directory is "zh-CN" and now i got this error, MISSING: APP/MATCH . HOME FOR LANGUAGE ZH-CN  please where i'm i supposed to placed the match.php file

Comment: Can you add your i18n component config to the question? It works fine for me when i put the match.php file into same directory where app.php is. But the `yii message` command creates the match.php file in `app` subfolder. It might be better to set the fileMap for that category as `'app/match' => 'app/match.php'` and leave it in that subfolder if you plan to use that command.